# Sqoop export hive table to RDBMS using Hive table name

Tags: hive, export

How to export Hive table data to RDBMS using sqoop, I am able to export Hive data from hive table path.

Comment: I want to use the Hive table name and export, sample code will help a lot.

Comment: What's your RDBM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to directly export from hive table, reference to HCATALOG is needed.  Also for the destination table, the case matters.  So for MySQL the table should be lower case but if Oracle it will be upper.  Following is an example in cloudera where destination database is MySQL.  I did not need to use --hcatalog-home or --hcatalog-database, but depending on your setup, it might be require.

```
sqoop export 
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db 
--username root -P 
--table mysql_test 
--hcatalog-table test
```